# Why wrap <div class="container"> about nav elements?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-inverse nav-tabs">
            <li><%= link_to "Home", '#'%></li>
            <li><%= link_to "About", '#'%></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Resume", '#'%></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Projects", '#'%></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Blog", '#'%></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to build my own website using Ruby on Rails and Bootstrap. I don't understand the purpose of `<div class="container">` around the nav-tab elements. If I leave the container out, the nav-tab elements look the same. But yet this seems to be the way most nav menu is created. Is this just convention?

Answer (score 3):

`class="container"` used around other content, such as the navigation or the grid system, will limit the width of child content to not exceed the width at any given breakpoint in the media queries, so that everything lines up and is centered and matches the width of the rest of the page. You won't be able to see that this is happening unless the content inside your navigation exceeds the width. If you had used the `.brand` and the default structure of the `.navbar`, you would.
Without a `.container`, the content will be the full width of the viewport.

It's helpful to view the un-packed CSS to see what you're working with:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Lines 1564-1584:

```
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .container {
        width: 750px
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
    .container {
        width: 970px
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
    .container {
        width: 1170px
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct, it was to begin with, some wackadoodle downvoted. I expanded on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This `<div>` is often used as a layout tool, because it can easily be positioned with CSS. And this position is then applied to the next, which should have the same alignment.

Usage example if you want to find it easier to work with different widths layout. You set just width of a packaging element, which is the `#container`, and the web are those stretches for a given resolution.

Example of basic HTML website layout:

```
<div id="container">
   <header>
       <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>Menu 1</li>
            <li>Menu 2</li>
            <li>Menu 3</li>
            <li>Menu 4</li>
          </ul>
       </nav>
   </header>
   <section>
        <article>
            Article 1
        </article>
        <article>
            Article 2
        </article>
   </section>
   <footer>
        Footer
   </footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 1000px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #container {
        width: 800px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    #container {
        width: 1300px;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many solutions, it's one of the many which web developers are used.